# Eclipse c++ launches visual studio when debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eclipse-cdt

I've just installed Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers version 4.9.0 and tried it with a simple test program. After having some problems I found that I should install MinGW too which I did and now my program compiles and I can run it outside of IDE. Then I created a debug configuration as explained in the help. But for some reason it launches Visual Studio when I start debugging and it doesn't hit any breakpoint neither in Eclipse nor in VS. It's strange - I expected it will use something from MinGW as a debugger, not VS.

So, what could I do wrong?

Comment: It's a shame. Eclipse is very good with Java so I believed it's same good with C++ too, but as I understand from the comments it's not.

Comment: Probably your preferences for the debugger are not correct. Please add details of what you have configured in Eclipse to your question.